If I throw a neutral conductor piece at the cathode of a high power battery; and after it bounces at me; will I get a current passing through me?
Yeah all I want to ask is in the title
Here is my thought experiment....
When the conductor piece hits the negative terminal a $\delta^+$ charge develops in the conductor piece and a $\delta^-$ will develop in the cathode (due to the difference in charges) due to which some electrons will flow into the conductor piece from the cathode to balance the $\delta^+ \delta^-$ charges. So now the conductor piece has some concrete charge $Q^-$. So when that conductor hits me will $Q^-$ flow through my body provided the battery is not enough and no charge is lost in the air and obviously if am grounded and I have no resistance????

Do you know "electric shock" means?

I know; Electric shock refers to a powerful current flowing throught the body..; atleast will any concrete; no matter how small current will generate through me if I have negligible resistance?

Will you get charge on the conductor? Yes you will. Will you get shocked by it? Potentially (pun intended)

Do you know how “powerful” it has to be? How long it has to last? And for what kind of harm? Do you know what your resistance is? And under what conditions?

Beyond all that I’m having difficulty making sense of the conditions you’re describing

You need to draw a diagram of the circuit that includes the body

Just think of my body as a simple wire connected to ground . I don't wanna know any effects or any details, just that will a concrete amount of current passing through me or not

You still need to draw a diagram of the source of the current if you want me to attempt an answer. And you need to say what "concrete" means.

In this answer, I walk through what happens, but in reality, I think this picture sums it up:

Take the grounded bit, and hold onto it.  That will be a useful but complicated detail later. Also important to note is that this sort of problem is sort of an oddity.  99% of it is electrostatics, but there's tiny points in time where the conductor touches something and electrons can move.
When the conductor touches the battery terminal, nothing happens. Wait, what? Okay, something happens but its more complicated. Electrons will flow, but where?  The answer is related to the electric field around the battery. In general this will cause additional electrons to flow into the conductor, but the specifics of how many and where is heavily geometry dependent.
When the conductor leaves the terminal, almost nothing happens.  There will be some shifting of electric fields, but nothing that will be major (I'm just including them for completeness).  So you are correct that the conductor will move through the air with more electrons than it had before.
When the conductor touches you, similar happens, and as you saw, charge does indeed flow from the conductor to you.
Mind you these charges are tiny.  It depends on the battery, of course.  But recognize that electric shocks which you feel are 3000 V and above.  Most batteries will have a much lower voltage, so the electrostatic potentials will be lower.
Now do it again.  This time, the battery is at a higher electrostatic potential -- there are physically fewer electrons remaining since you took some away.  So when the conductor touches the electrode again, fewer electrons transfer (I believe this will be exponentially fewer, but it might depend on things I'm not thinking of). And when it touches your body, you have more charge on you, so fewer electrons move onto your body.
Do this a few times, and you will reach an equilibrum.  If you work out the math, with perfect insulation, your body will have exactly enough charge to have a potential exactly that of the electrode of the battery.  Touching the terminal directly would have been faster, but in the end you accomplish the same effect.
Now let's add the ground into the mix.  What does this do?  Well, the ground is a huge body, so you can sink lots of electrons.  If you're not wearing highly resistive shoes, the electrons will spread across the earth.  This will negate the secondary effect mentioned, where fewer electrons transfer to you.  Also, we have to ask about the other side of the battery.  Is it connected to ground?  If so, you form a sort of circuit, allowing electrons to flow back into the battery.  This will mean that the terminal you touch has the same number of electrons each time you touch it.
I mentioned electric fields a few times.  You will eventually learn about something called a capacitor, which stores energy in the electric field between two conductive plates.  This effect is non-trivial in this case. The ground acts like one big plate, and you end up storing energy between that ground plate and your objects (like the conductor).  You'll find the math doesn't work out well unless you account for this.
Now there were lots of effects here.  Some of them easy to follow, some hard.  But, if we make a minor change to your construction, we can physically demonstrate the effect.  Instead of having a conductive rod, which transfers little bits of charge, replace it with a rubber belt.  Each little bit of the belt can hold a little bit of charge. The transfer of electrons is a little different, relying on electrostatic induction, but the result is the same.  And instead of a battery terminal, run the belt across a "comb" of pointed wires.  Sharp corners concentrate electric potential, making the result more pronounced. Use a similar comb apparatus at the other end of the belt. The result is like a continuous stream of charge carriers flowing from the source to the destination.  The result is called a Van de Graffe generator, and can be used to generate megavolts of static electricity.
The Van de Graffe generator is quite famous.  We recognize its shape anywhere.  And its proof that this approach causes charge to flow.  It isn't quite the same, but its similar.  And, in fact, it was apparently inspired by something akin to your setup:

A more immediate inspiration for Van de Graaff was a generator W. F. G. Swann was developing in the 1920s in which charge was transported to an electrode by falling metal balls, thus returning to the principle of the Kelvin water dropper.


“But recognize that electric shocks which you feel are 3000 V and above.” What is your source for this statement?

@BobD Source is my own ESD training, but it's a reasonably easy number to find  (That link wasn't my source, I just googled for it)

(That voltage is for ESD shocks, which is the kind of shock applicable here.  We notice continuous current at much lower voltages.  Normal 60Hz AC we feel at around 50V, give or take)

A 5kv ESD can be harmless or fatal depending on the capacitance

@BobD True, there is the question of how many coulombs are transmitted.  But 3kV is apparently the threshold for feeling it.  This is a challenge for ESD components because many are permanently damaged below this threshold.  Without proper ESD gear, you can damage the item and not even know you did.
